# How to find duplicates in list and sort them by number of appearance

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Is there a easy way to find duplicates in list, and then sort them by number of appearance? Also, duplicates should be removed.

Eg. you have a `List<String>` like this:

```
List<String> = new List<String>{"6","1","2","2","4","6","5","1","6","6","2"};
```

Question is, how to convert this list into -> "6", "1", "2", "4", "5"?

Comment: I don't believe your example orders them by numbr of appearances: I count 4x 6, 2x 1, 3x 2, 1x 4 and 1x 5 so the result should be 6 2 1 4 5

Comment: I believe Miller means order of first appearance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Linq.Distinct()`

```
List<String> list = new List<String>{"6","1","2","2","4","6","5","1","6","6","2"};
list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I've just realised that this will actually provide the correct order, just not for the correct reason. Actually no, cancel that, the example has the wrong ordering. :-/

Comment: @rawling, may be he mean first appearance

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to use LINQ method [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx):

```
var originalList = …;
vat withoutDuplicates = originalList.Distinct();
```

Though you should note that the order of the result of `Distinct()` is explicitly left undocumented.

Comment: This doesn't perform the requested ordering. (Actually, neither does the example.)

Comment: @Rawling I think “by number of appearance” is supposed to mean “by the order of appearance”.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want them ordered from most common to least - unlike your example -

```
var ordered = list
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

should achieve this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the right answer for the sample output. I think you misunderstood what “number of appearance” is supposed to mean (though it is unclear).

Comment: The suspense is killing me :)

Comment: @Rawling, Question is, how to convert this list into -> "6", "1", "2", "4", "5"? you convert to "6", "2", "1", "4", "5"

Comment: +1 because I think the question is badly phrased with the sort by number of appearance (although i do think he meant in order of first appearance so correct answer is probably just the distinct call)

Answer (score 0):

```
Using System.Linq;
// Assuming inputList was the original string list
List<String> deDuped = inputList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unclear exactly what you mean, here's a solution for two possible meanings:

1. **Get a unique list ordered by the number of occurrences**:

   Group the list and sort by `Count()`:

   ```
   List<String> list = new List<String>{"6","1","2","2","4","6","5","1","6","6","2"};

   var q = from s in list
   group s by s into g
   orderby g.Count() descending
   select g.Key;
   ```
2. **Get a unique list ordered by the FIRST occurrence of the item in the list**

   There are already several suggestions to use `Distinct`, however the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) DOES NOT GUARANTEE that they appear in the order they appear in the list (the current `Enumerable` implementation happens to order them that way, but for other providers it's not guaranteed):

   > **Remarks**
   >   The result sequence is unordered.

   To guarantee order, add an OrderBy clause:

   ```
   var q = list.Distinct().OrderBy(s => list.IndexOf(s));
   ```

Comment: The way you guarantee order using `IndexOf()` can be very slow (it's O(n²)).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the cleanest yet, but this provides the correct result.

```
var originalData = new List<string>{"6","1","2","2","4","6","5","1","6","6","2"};
var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var myString in originalData)
{
    if (!result.Exists(s => s == myString))
        result.Add(myString);
}
```