# Does Linq List.Distinct() also sort and orders the list according to number of appearances

Tags: c#, linq

I just saw [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371975/how-to-find-duplicates-in-list-and-sort-them-by-number-of-appearance)   and I am a bit confused by the accepted answer

```
List<String> list = new List<String>{"6","1","2","2","4","6","5","1","6","6","2"};
list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

So is the `list.Distict().ToList()` also sorts according to number of occurrences? How I mean what criteria if it is a complex list then what?

Comment: You are confused by the answer because the question itself is confusingly ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is the list.Distict().ToList() also sorts according to number of
>   occurrences?

No it doesn't. It just returns distinct elements from the list by using default equality comparer to compare values.

[`Enumerable.Distinct<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The Distinct(IEnumerable) method **returns an
>   unordered sequence** that contains no duplicate values. It uses the
>   default equality comparer, Default, to compare values.

Answer (score 3):

> So is the list.Distict().ToList() also sorts according to number of occurrences?

No, it does not. `Distinct()` is allowed to reorder the sequence in any way it finds useful.

> How I mean what criteria if it is a complex list then what?

If you need the list sorted in any particular order, you can force it yourself. If you would like to keep the original order, you can do it with a somewhat more complex query:

```
var unique = list
    .Select((v,i) => new {v, i})
    .GroupBy(p => p.v)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Min(p => p.i))
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/pgpe9P)

If you would like to order based on the number of occurrences, use this query:

```
var unique = list
    .GroupBy(p => p)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Count()) // Items with smaller count are first
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/swujnq)

Comment: While it is not specifically documented as a constraint, in actual implementation, `Distinct` is going to yield the items in the order that they first appear (simply because this is the easiest solution) and it isn't going to be based on hash codes or anything like that.

Comment: @Servy You are right, [it looks like that's what it does (line 706-715)](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs).

Comment: Well it's the most sensible implementation.  If another more arbitrary ordering would be easier, then I'm sure they'd use that, but any other ordering would result in deferring execution less, which is only a disadvantage.